# TypeScript foreach() with async http request

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, foreach

I have an Issue with my angular webapp.
I am trying to iterate over an array and make each time a HTTP request to obtain the ID to the `Module`, which is an Object:

`{name:string, charge:string}`

Once I have updated every Module with the new property `id`, I want to do some stuff with these IDs. For that I need all the IDs and cannot process each `Module` individually. How do I achieve that? I know, because the `http.get()` function within Angular is async I cannot simply paste my code after the `foreach()` loop.

Here is my code:

```
ngOnInit() {
let fit = parseFit(megafit.default.fit);
fit.modules.forEach(Module => {
  this.http.get(`https://esi.tech.ccp.is/v2/search/?categories=inventory_type&search=${Module.name}&strict=true`)
  .subscribe((data:any) => {
    Module.id = data.inventory_type
  })
});
// Do something with all the IDs
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some RxJS Operators to to this.

Use [from](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html) to make `Module[]` to `Observable<Module>` then Pipe the stream into [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) and perform the api request. Use [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) to alter your module Object with the result from API and at last use toArray to collect the responses. Subscribe to the stream to do the action you'll want to to when all modules are processed.

example:

```js
from(fit.modules).pipe(
    mergeMap(module => this.http.get(...).pipe(
        tap(apiResponse => module.id = apiResponse.inventory_type)
    )),
    toArray()
).subscribe(allResponses => {
    // do your action
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use promises instead of subscribers

```
ngOnInit() {
let fit = parseFit(megafit.default.fit);
const jarOfPromises =[];
fit.modules.forEach(Module => {
jarOfPromises.push(
  this.http.get(`https://esi.tech.ccp.is/v2/search/?categories=inventory_type&search=${Module.name}&strict=true`)
  .toPromise())
});

Promise.all(jarOfPromises).then(results=>{
/** your code **/
});
```

Be advised I wrote this in my cell phone

Comment: why should OP use promises instead of observables?

Comment: It’s just a way of achieving what he/she is asking for. In this case I think it is easier to use promises instead of  more complex RXJS operators